# How to count results from untyped IQueryable on the DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, iqueryable

In my code, I am getting back a value of type [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=net-6.0) - yes, the untyped, non-generic version. I am getting this `IQueryable` object from OData, so I neither know (at compile time) what the query looks like nor what type the results are.

Under certain circumstances, I would like to count the results from this `IQueryable`. For performance reasons, I need to rely on Entity Framework to translate this count instruction to SQL and only fetch the resulting number from the DB, rather than retrieving all the (> 1,000,000) items from the DB and then having the .NET runtime count them.

Unfortunately, it seems the non-generic version of `IQueryable` does not have a `Count()` extension method, while any of my attempts to convert the non-generic `IQueryable` into a generic `IQueryable` (e.g. by calling `.Cast<object>()`) have resulted in the results getting pulled from the DB into the C# side to be counted there.

**How do I get the number of results from that `IQueryable` directly from the DB?**

Comment: import System.Linq. There is an extension there to Count()

Comment: @tval: Which extension method in which class is that, exactly? I can only see extensions that require `IQueryable<T>` there.

Comment: IQueryable without the extenssion <T> inherits from IEnumerable. You will have to iterate over the items to create a count, or cast it into a list to get the count. Otherwise, as the documentation says, it is supposed to be implemented by providers that inherit IQueryable<T>. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=net-6.0

Comment: @tval: "You will have to iterate over the items to create a count, or cast it into a list to get the count" - both of these options are obviously inacceptable, as they fetch (again, > 1,000,000) items from the DB into memory rather than just retrieving a single number representing the number of items.

Comment: @tval: "it is supposed to be implemented by providers that inherit IQueryable<T>" - it *is*. That is, in the debugger, I can see that the `IQueryable` instance is also an `IQueryable<T>` instance. I just don't know the `T` at compile-time (it can be an arbitrary entity type depending on where my code is called). I *have* found a solution using reflection, but I'm pretty sure there must be a better way ...

Comment: What you are asking then is for an Object to return a count. Objects, do not have a count method. Count can only come from Enumerable<T>. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-6.0

Comment: @tval: No, I am asking for counting the results of an `IQueryable`. I can retrieve the result set from said `IQueryable`, which is an enumeration of items (and thus can be counted) - same as would be the case with an `IQueryable<T>`. What I fail to do is count these items without enumerating them (as it would be possible with an `IQueryable<T>`).